# "Variadic enum cases are not supported" swift 5 error

Tags: swift, swift5

I am getting `Variadic enum cases are not supported` error in following code. This was compiling and working fine in Swift4, but giving compile time error in Swift5, Xcode 10.2

```
enum ModelRule {
        case required(keys: String...) // error: Variadic enum cases are not supported
        case nonEmptyString(keys: String...) // error: Variadic enum cases are not supported
        case emptyString(key: String)
}
```

while the message is very clear, I would like to know why would they remove perfectly working feature? Or am I missing something here?

Also, is there any better solution to above error than following ?
`case required(keys: [String])`

Comment: It isn't perfectly working feature in Swift 4, I'm getting crashes. For the last question: you can always add convenient `static func` with variadic params that will return the enum case.

Comment: @user28434: please put this as answer, so that I can accept it. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding the comment:

You should have arrays in associated values of cases. But for convenience create methods with variadic parameters.

Example:

```
enum ModelRule {
    case required(keys: [String])
    case nonEmptyString(keys: [String])
    case emptyString(key: String)

    init(required keys: String...) { // It could be static func, but init here works and looks better
        self = .required(keys: keys)
    }

    init(nonEmptyString keys: String...) {
        self = .nonEmptyString(keys: keys)
    }

    init(emptyString key: String) { // Added this just for my OCD, not actually required
        self = .emptyString(key: key)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let required = ModelRule(required: "a", "b", "c") // .required(keys: ["a", "b", "c"])
let nonEmpty = ModelRule(nonEmptyString: "d", "e", "f") // .nonEmptyString(keys: ["d", "e", "f"])
let empty = ModelRule(emptyString: "g") // .emptyString(key: "g")
```

Answer (score 3):

Variadic parameter used to work on swift 4 but it wasn't intentionally.
Just use arrays

```
enum ModelRule {
    case required(keys: [String])
    case nonEmptyString(keys: [String])
    case emptyString(key: String)
}
```

See [Swift Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use static functions to mimic cases with variadic argument:

```
enum ModelRule {
    case required(keys: [String])
    case nonEmptyString(keys: [String])
    case emptyString(key: String)

    static func required(keys: String...) -> Self {
        .required(keys: keys)
    }

    static func nonEmptyString(keys: String...) -> Self {
        .nonEmptyString(keys: keys)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ruleChecker.apply(rule: .required(keys: "a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: I love this answer because you get the same syntax at the usage site.